# A usage of verb "prefer"

Tags: meaning, grammar, verbs, usage

I am Korean English learner.

This is a sentence from TOEFL.

> I prefer spending time with just a few friends to hanging out with a large group since one can cultivate more profound relationships and talk about things on a more personal level.

Here in this sentence, I am interested in the usage of "prefer".

I already learned that the transitive verb "prefer" has different meanings and usages.

Here "prefer" is used as kind of comparative function: a person prefer spending time with just a few friends "more than" hanging out with a large group.

Also I looked up dictionary for sure,

- prefer + object
- prefer + object + pp NP
- prefer + doing
- prefer + to VP (rather than)

and I am curious that if I change the sentence into

> I prefer to spend time with just a few friends to hang out with a large group.

is it a grammatical sentence?

Also if this sentence is accepted (if this paraphrasing is accepted),

Is the first model sentence more acceptable than my paraphrased sentence?
If so, then why?

Comment: Why did you change "hanging out" to "hang out"?

Comment: yes! I changed both spending and hanging

Comment: @user3169 I think Belle was reasoning by analogy and attempting parallel construction!  A good try.  Wrong, but a good try.  See, this is what trying to apply logic to English gets you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your reasoning is sound, but the rephrased version doesn't quite work.

When you switch to the infinitive form of the verb, you need to add *would* and replace the second *to* with *rather than*:

> I *would* prefer to spend time with just a few friends *rather than* hang out with a large group.

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/common-verbs/prefer) has some more information about using *prefer*.

Comment: Also acceptable: "I prefer to spend time with just a few friends, *rather than **hanging*** out with a large group."

Comment: @1006a Oh, indeed. Once you start mixing verb forms it gets more interesting. Then there are constructions based on *I would rather* and *I like X more*, among others.

Comment: @Jason Bassford thank you so much! I learned a lot from your explanation:)